# Clarification on Support in Diplomacy

Tags: diplomacy

The relevant moves are as follows.

`England:
Denmark -> Kiel
Sweden Support Denmark Hold
North Sea Support Denmark Hold`


`Germany:
Berlin -> Kiel
Skagerrack -> Denmark
Blatic Sea Support Skagerrack -> Denmark
Helgoland Bight Support Skagerrack -> Denmark`

Does the support fail for Denmark because Denmark attempted to move to Kiel, even though it bounces.

Comment: Yes, Denmark is ousted by Skagerrak. A unit order to move invalidates the orders supporting it to hold. See Dan Tilken's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support fails. From [the bottom right of page 7 in the rules.](https://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/diplomacy.pdf)

> A unit not ordered to move can be supported by a support order that only mentions its province.

and

> A unit ordered to move can only be supported by a support order that matches the move the unit is trying to make.

Comment: You should clarify (emphasize) that Skagerrak **doesn't bounce**, it moves to Denmark because the rule you quoted specifically *disallows* Denmark from being supported holding while it is attempting to move.